# filter strings to display three letters from the ArrayList in java

Tags: string, arraylist, filter, substring, string-length

I was implementing the method filter that returns a sublist of all the strings in list whose length are larger than 3. I called the filter() in the main function after I added three sample data - Hello Sam Washington. The output should be Hel Sam Was. Suggestions?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class practice {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> filter() {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).length() > 3)
                list.set(i, list.get(i).substring(0, 3));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("Hello");
        list1.add("Sam");
        list1.add("Washington");

        filter();

        for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(list1.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating the class Practice. You should do that and fill its `list` list and then call filter. I am just pasting the main method for you here.

```
Practice practice = new Practice();
practice.list.add("Hello");
practice.list.add("Sam");
practice.list.add("Washington");

practice.filter();

for(int i=0; i<practice.list.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(practice.list.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `list` from `filter` without using the returned value, or actually passing in `list1`. You can either add the items to `list` instead, or redo your method like so:

```
public ArrayList<String> filter(ArrayList<String> toFilter) {
    for(int i=0; i<toFilter.size(); i++) {
        if(toFilter.get(i).length() > 3)
            toFilter.set(i, toFilter.get(i).substring(0, 3));
    }
    return toFilter;
}
```

and then change the line `filter();` to `list1 = filter();`, so you capture the result of the filtering.